# Ubuntu 20.04 How to cast videos to AmazonFireStick Or Screen mirroring

Tags: screen, mirrors, screencast

Friends,
I am using Ubuntu 20.04 persistence from a pen-drive. I would like to cast videos to my LG TV(NON Android) using my Amazon Fire Stick.
Basic requirement is running my HP laptop local videos to my TV (or via Amazon FireStick). All are connected to same network via Wifi.

Comment: Does your LG have built-in Chromecast, or Mirror capabilities? I'd wager not. Firestick has neither, as far as I know... well, maybe Mirror...

Comment: no @heynnema chrome cast is not there.  I have to use hdmi. do u kno how to duplicate screen from Ubuntu over hdmi ?

Comment: Can't tell you how to do that... other than connect HDMI and set Displays settings panel to mirror.